# Powershell sub-expression syntax used by TFS/Azure Devops

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops

TFS/Azure DevOps allows you to reference custom variables and built in build/release variables using [the following syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts):

```
$(variable_name)
```

For example, if I wanted to grab the build definition name, I would grab the value from the following sub-expression:

```
$(Build.DefinitionName)
```

But, as far as I can tell, the above syntax **is not a valid powershell sub-expression**.

If "Build.DefinitionName" was a variable, it would need to look like:

```
$($Build.DefinitionName)
```

If it were a collection/hashtable, it would use curly braces:

```
${Build.DefinitionName}
```

If it were an object with a static property, it would be:

```
${Build::DefinitionName}
```

So what the heck is "Build" in the above example? Is TFS/VSTS/Azure DevOps doing some magic string replacement here or something?

Comment: It's just an environment variable.  If you have special characters in the key, you need to use a variable delimeter: `${Env:Build.DefinitionName}`.  All of the examples in your question are invalid, btw.  You need to have the variable, then the dereference: `${Build}::DefinitionName`

Comment: They are definitely not invalid. I use them all over the place and they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a Powershell language element, it's a simple TFS/VSTS placeholder syntax, just like SQLCMD uses: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables?view=sql-server-2017

TFS/VSTS inserts the values for these placeholders before invoking your Powershell tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Build/release variables are made available to processes running in the scope of a build/release in the form of environment variables.

As an example, the build definition name is available the same way you'd access any other environment variable in PowerShell: `$env:BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME`. Note that periods are replaced with underscores.

The exception is secrets. Anything defined as a secret will have to be explicitly passed in to the consuming script, as they are not populated as environment variables.